# Uniquifying a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, unique

Up until now I have been using this code to uniquify (remove duplicates) from list in python:

`my_list = list(set(my_list))`

I now have a list of lists, I want to be able to remove duplicates from within the list of lists. For example:

`(['possible-duplicate', 'random-data'], ['possible-duplicate', 'random-data'], ['possible-duplicate', 'random-data'])`

I want to remove the whole sublist if `possible-duplicate` is a duplicate.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: do you care about keeping the data in this format? because there's a way to essentially "flatten" all your lists so that regardless of how many lists of lists of lists of lists, it will return to you one list with all the data at "the same level" after which you can use the set function to remove duplicates. You can't go back with this method though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a dictionary from your data:

```
data = (['possible-duplicate', '12345'], 
        ['not-a-duplicate', '54321'],
        ['possible-duplicate', '51423'])
data_unique = dict(data)
```

Result is `{'not-a-duplicate': '54321', 'possible-duplicate': '51423'}`, or if you prefer a list of tuples, use `date_unique.items()`, which gives you `[('not-a-duplicate', '54321'), ('possible-duplicate', '51423')]`.

Or for the more general case, where the sublists have more than two elements, you can use this

```
data_unique = dict((d[0], d) for d in data)
```

and then use `data_unique.values()` to reclaim the "uniquified" list.

Comment: Yes, assuming the question is representative for the actual usecase.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Added alternative for general case. Better now? :-)

Comment: I gave you plus 1 already for your other answer ... since given his example input that would work fine

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks! But it was in fact a valid objection, so I wanted to fix it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
seen = set()

[sublist for sublist in my_list if sublist[0] not in seen and not seen.add(sublist[0])]
```

This happens to preserve order as well, which `list(set(...))` does not.

Comment: I don't think that using the `if` clause of a comprehension for side-effects is recommendable. It doesn't really add to readability and maintainability, but tends more to magic. Although this answer with `and not seen.add()` already has appeared various times on SO.